# Angular 2 and Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, systemjs

I've been following the tutorial https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html to implement Jasmine with Angular 2 using the Tour of Heroes tutorial.

Everything works fine when I test with "hero.spec". However when I try to test "app.component.ts" with a unit test file I named "app.spec" System JS does not append "js" to it. I receive the following errors:

```
angular2-polyfills.js:126 GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/src/test/app.component 404 (Not Found)`

system.src.js:1068 GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/angular2/core 404 (Not Found)
```

The app.spec.ts file is as follows:

```
import { AppComponent } from 'app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {

let app : AppComponent;

beforeEach(() => {
    app = new AppComponent();
});

it('true to be true', () => {
    expect(true).toEqual(true);
});

});
```

The unit test file is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>Ng App Unit Tests</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">
<script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- #1. add the system.js library -->
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<script>
    // #2. Configure systemjs to use the .js extension
    //     for imports from the app folder
    System.config({
        packages: {
            'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
        }
    });

     // #3. Import the spec files explicitly
    Promise.all([
            System.import('app/app.spec'),
            System.import('app/app.component')
        ])

            // #4. wait for all imports to load ...
            //     then re-execute `window.onload` which
            //     triggers the Jasmine test-runner start
            //     or explain what went wrong.
            .then(window.onload)
            .catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It looks like it's System JS appending "js" to "app.spec" but not "app.component" or others. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try defaultJSExtensions: true in your System.config?

Comment: @echonax indeed, didn't look closely enough. good question - I bet that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `import { AppComponent } from './app.component'`
Or if app.component is under app folder:
`'./app/app.component'`.
Is the spec file on the same folder as the component?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you forgot to import some JS files into your HTML file because I see a 404 error for the `angular2/core` module. Moreover I don't think that you need to import the module that you want to test (`app.component`) in your case since it will be imported within your test module.

Moreover I see that you test file isn't located under the `app` folder since SystemJS tries to load it through this URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/src/test/app.component`. You only configure the `app` folder. That's why the tool doesn't append the `js` extension to it.

Here is what I would use in your HTML file:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/typescript@1.8.2/lib/typescript.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/testing.dev.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/boot.js"></script>

<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    } 
  });
  System.import('angular2/src/platform/browser/browser_adapter')
    .then(function(browser_adapter) { browser_adapter.BrowserDomAdapter.makeCurrent(); })
    .then(function() {
      System.import('app/foo.bar.spec')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console))
        .then(window.onload);
    })
</script>
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/YAVD4s?p=preview.